# Can I use the @Resource annotation in a setter instead of a field?

Tags: java, spring, resources

I currently I have:

```
@Resource(name = "my.map")
private Map<String, String> externalMap;
```

Can I use the resource annotation in the setter instead with the same result?

Like this?

```
private Map<String, String> externalMap;
@Resource(name = "my.map")
void setExternalMap(Map<String,String> aMap) {
    this.externalMap = aMap;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [JavaDoc for the Resource Annotation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/annotation/Resource.html), the annotation may be applied to a class, or fields or methods.  Requested resources will be injected into the method.  [An example of this usage exists here.](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bncjk.html#bncjm)